# Crawler is not Running inside django views stopping after Spyder Opened

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run scrapy spider inside django views. It is not working.
When I triggered the url, It get response Http 200 Ok. But Crawler is not fetching anything from the urls.
If this is not the best practise please provide the details for running scrapy inside Django.

this is my logs output:

```
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:17:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:18:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
app_1      | ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:18:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
app_1      | ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
app_1      |  'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:18:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
app_1      | ['covid19crawler.pipelines.Covid19CrawlerPipeline',
app_1      |  'covid19crawler.pipelines.CSVPipeline']
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:18:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:18:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
app_1      | 2020-05-16 06:18:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
```

My Spider Code:

```
class Covid19(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'covid19'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'covid19crawler.pipelines.Covid19CrawlerPipeline': 300,
            'covid19crawler.pipelines.CSVPipeline': 500,
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        def item(i):
            items['countries'] = countries[i]
            items['total_cases'] = total_cases[i]
            items['new_cases'] = new_cases[i]
            items['total_recovered'] = total_recovered[i]
            items['active_cases'] = active_cases[i]
            items['total_cases_per_million'] = total_cases_per_million[i]
            items['death_per_million'] = death_per_million[i]
            items['total_deaths'] = total_deaths[i]
            items['new_deaths'] = new_deaths[i]

        t = response.css('table')
        countries = []
        total_cases = []
        new_cases = []
        total_deaths = []
        total_recovered = []
        active_cases = []
        total_cases_per_million = []
        death_per_million = []
        new_deaths = []
        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(2) a::text').extract()[0:205]:
            countries.append(data)

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(3)')[8:213]:
            value = data.css('::text').get(default='0')
            total_cases.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(4)')[8:213]:
            value = "".join(data.css('::text').get(default='0'))
            new_cases.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(5)')[8:213]:
            value = data.css('::text').get(default=0)
            if value == ' ' or value == '  ':
                value = '0'
            total_deaths.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(6)')[8:213]:
            value = "".join(data.css('::text').get(default='0'))
            new_deaths.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(7)')[8:213]:
            value = "".join(data.css('::text').get(default='0'))
            total_recovered.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(8)')[8:213]:
            value = "".join(data.css('::text').get(default='0'))
            active_cases.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(10)')[8:213]:
            value = "".join(data.css('::text').get(default='0'))
            total_cases_per_million.append(to_num(value))

        for data in t.css('td:nth-child(11)')[8:213]:
            value = "".join(data.css('::text').get(default='0'))
            death_per_million.append(to_num(value))

        WorldCovidStats.objects.all().delete()
        for i in range(205):
            items = Covid19CrawlerItem()
            item(i)
            WorldCovidStats.objects.create(country=items['countries'],
                                           total_case=items['total_cases'],
                                           new_case=items['new_cases'],
                                           total_recovered=items['total_recovered'],
                                           active_case=items['active_cases'],
                                           cases_per_million=items['total_cases_per_million'],
                                           deaths_per_million=items['death_per_million'],
                                           total_death=items['total_deaths'],
                                           new_death=items['new_deaths'])

        for i in range(len(total_cases)):
            items = Covid19CrawlerItem()
            item(i)
            yield items
```

My Django View:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def run_scrapy(request):
    """Views for running all scrapy spyder"""
    crawler_settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = CrawlerRunner(crawler_settings)
    run = crawler.crawl(Covid19)
    return Response()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve using multiprocessing and CrawlerProcess

Spider Code:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
....
@staticmethod
def crawl(url):
    crawler_settings = get_project_settings()
    process = CrawlerProcess(crawler_settings)
    process.crawl(Covid19)
    process.start()
```

Django View:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

@api_view(('GET',))
def run_scrapy(request):
    pool = mp.Pool()
    covid_spider = Covid19()
    pool.apply_async(covid_spider.crawl)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```